# How do I configure routing for MVC and SignalR in an ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-routing

I'm trying to build a web app with ASP.NET Core 2.1.0-preview1 and ASP.NET Core SignalR 1.0.0-alpha1 with an Angular4 client. So far I've been able to muddle through and can actually open a SignalR web socket connection from within the client. That came at a price, though, here's an excerpt of my `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

   /*routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
      name: "spa-fallback",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });*/
});

app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
   routes.MapHub<Feed>("feed");
});
```

As you can see, I had to disable the "spa-fallback" route, if I didn't do that SignalR would receive plain HTML instead of JSON. The drawback of that, of course, is that I have to enter the exact URL (`localhost:12345/home/index`, for example) now, which sucks.

So my question is, how can I make MVC routing and SignalR routing live side by side?

Comment: Does it work if you put `UseSignalR`before `UseMvc`? Also, you shouldn't need `UseWebSockets` - `UseSignalR` does this for you.

Comment: Yep, that's what I've come up in the meantime as well. Thanks for the pointer regarding web sockets!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put `UseSignalR` before `UseMvc` otherwise the fallback route will be registered before routes added by `UseSignalR`.